# как почистить /var/lib/docker/network/files/

Tags: docker

В папке

> /var/lib/docker/network/files/

тысячи файлов и размер 8.9Gb.
Стандартными средствами уже очистку провел. целевую папку это не затронуло
Как можно безопасно освободить место и что это вообще за файлы?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: [`$ sudo find /var/lib/docker/network/files/ -name '*.sock' -delete`](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/27893)

Comment: я намеренно вставил картинку чтобы показать состояние системы

Comment: подскажите насколко данная операция безопасна?